# google maps marker loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, marker

I want to display an alert with the marker info when I click on it. I receive the parameters as a json and my problem is when I click any marker, it is always displaying the info of the last marker. I don´t know where the problem can be.

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                        mapOptions);

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        var userPos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                position.coords.longitude)
                        var markUsr = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: userPos,
                            map: map,
                            icon: 'images/locblue.png'
                        });

                        map.setCenter(markUsr.position);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitud, data[i].longitud)

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: pos,
                                map: map,
                                icon: 'images/locred.png',
                                description: data[i].desc
                            });

                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: data[i].name
                            });

                            infowindow.open(map, marker)
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                alert(marker.description)
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had almost the exact same problem with Google Maps. As far as I understand (which would explain the problem and solution), when you click a marker, JS essentially goes back to the scope of wherever `google.maps.event.addListener` is called. However, it doesn't store `n` (`data.length`) different `marker` variables. It just remembers the last one.

To solve this, create a list of markers before the for loop, and reference indices in the list instead of just one `marker` variable. Store the index of each marker in an `id` property to keep it available. Like this:

```
...

map.setCenter(markUsr.position);
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitud, data[i].longitud);

    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: 'images/locred.png',
        description: data[i].desc,
        id: i
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: data[i].name
    });

    infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
        alert(markers[this.id].description)
    })
}

...
```

Sometimes JS can be very unintuitive, but this is how I solved it.

As a side note, you were missing a couple of semicolons.

Comment: it does not show anything, with your answer I think the problem is in the alert line with the variable i. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Edited. See if it works when storing the index of each marker in its `id`.

Answer (score 1):

JS allowed me to do this in a forEach.  Every time I tried to break the marker function out onto its own, I would get 0 results on the map.  Somehow this magically works where having the marker function in it's own function and calling it via for loop doesn't work.  I really don't know what but thought I would share another solution.  This plotted over 200 points on the same map for me :)

```
dataSet.forEach((item, index) => {
    coords = {lat:item[2], lng:item[3]}
    if(item[1] > 500){
        color = 'red';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map:map,
                icon: {
                url: `http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/${color}-dot.png`
                }
            });
    }
    else if((item[1] < 500) && (item[1] > 100)){
        color = 'pink';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map:map,
                icon: {
                url: `http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/${color}-dot.png`
                }
            });
    }
    else{
        color = 'blue';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map:map,
                icon: {
                url: `http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/${color}-dot.png`
                }
            });
    }
})
```